# Authoring tool for multi media interactive mini applications

Tags: programming, presentation, children

I'm looking for an alternative to the discontinued MatchWare Mediator:

Mediator was a Windows software, meant for authoring interactive multimedia-based presentations. It was an easy to learn and very versatile software featuring a visual programming language. Its interface was similar to PowerPoint, meaning it was page-driven and you could easily add images, movies and text, but also text input fields, push buttons and list boxes. Its programming capabilities were event-driven, such that you could e.g. add a push button, add a hover event to it and use the visual programming language to move the button away as soon as the mouse cursor reaches it.

I'm looking for *any* replacement for a multimedia authoring tool, that is easy to learn and powerful enough to create something like a point-and-click-adventure, "Cookie Clicker", or maybe some simple jump-and-run-game.
It has to be able to export the creations in a way that you can run it without having the authoring tool installed itself, e.g. HTML5 or some folder containing a run-time.

I'm planning to use it with children (10yo+), so the learning curve should not be too steep.

It's a plus if it runs on Windows 7 and later, but I'm kind of desperate right know, so I'm looking for just anything that remotely covers my requirements. Any suggestions for any platform and of any price or technology are appreciated.

I did some research and I'm already aware that there are relatively simple to use game makers, which have comparable features.